# why a function in class do nothing but return another function in the same class?

Tags: python, function, return

when I read a code in python, I got a problem that confused me very much.

```
class WordCloud(object):
    def fit_word(self, frequencies):
        """..."""
        return self.generate_from_frequencies(frequencies)

    def generate_from_frequencies(self, frequencies, max_font_size=None):
        """..."""
        ...
```

My question is why the function "fit_word" do nothing but only return "generate_from_frequencies", what does this help?

Comment: We can't see the whole code. `generate_from_frequencies` might be a generic method used by several other methods and the name of that method wouldn't be clear in terms of the API to be called by itself. In this instance it happens that `fit_word` (which, as a name, seems more like it's to be used as part of an API) only needs to call that one method. I can only speculate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is usually done when you want to simplify usage or hide a certain behavior from the end user.

For example:

```
class Text:
    def _change_color(self, r, g, b):
        self.text_color = (r, g, b)

    def change_to_yellow(self):
        self._change_color(255, 255, 0)

    def change_to_blue(self):
        self._change_color(0, 0, 255)
    .
    .
    .
```

You may not want/expect the user to know the RGB codes of all the colors, so instead you provide few helpers methods that wrap the internal behavior of `_change_color`.

With that said, the exact example you provided indeed seems a bit redundant as it does not encapsulate any internal or complicated behavior.

Another possibility is that `generate_from_frequencies` is a generic method, and `fit_word` was deemed a special/frequent enough use case that it was worth being a method of its own.

For example:

```
class Text:
    def change_location(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def center_text(self):
        self.change_location(SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2)

    def move_left(self):
        self.change_location(0, self.y)
    .
    .
    .
```